# Magento 2 :: Fetches the value of PageId and PageIdentifier from cache

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache

I'm trying to get the `Page ID` and `Page Identifier` in the `footer.phtml` template file using the below methods but getting the values from the page cache on the storefront.

**Using ObjectManager Method:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

echo $cmsPage->getIdentifier(); //Get Current CMS Page Identifier
echo $cmsPage->getId(); //Get Current CMS Page ID
```

**Using getRequest Method:**

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
```

Both methods take the value from caches and give the wrong value on page loads.

How do I prevent these cache values and get the proper page identifier value on every page even if the page is loaded using the same browser?

Can anyone please suggest me?

Comment: You'd place that calls in a non cached block, or define some different cache policy for footer (not recommended, as it should be common in all pages)

Comment: Thanks @RaulSanchez I created a non-cached custom block and called it in the head section. Now I'm getting proper values for the page identifier on every page of my site.